# What are the meanings of IO-related rates?

Tags: linux, io, top, profile, htop

I found in the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/htop.1.html) short explanations for the abbreviations. But I have no idea about what their values stand for (how large is good, how large is bad).

How do I know if the IO is too busy and what makes the load too heavy?

[image: htop]

[image: snapshot of top]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fixed value because it depends on the computer's specifications as well as the programs that are running on it.

What your snap shot tells us is that your machine is mostly loaded on CPU processing and not I/O bound.

I personally prefer the regular `top` to get a global view of the machine.  Its `wa` (wait %) indicator in the header is a good way to see how I/O bound the machine really is.

A production server's load should normally be kept under 2 * number_of_cores to ensure it remains reasonably responsive.  Obviously, most tasks will be processed faster if the load is below the number of cores.

Comment: @JuliePeletier  hi, I attached the snapshot of `top` but didn't find `wa` in the header.  Concerning `2 * number_of_core` do you refer to the load averages of CPU?

Comment: `wa` is just below `stopped` and is at `0.0%`.  This machine is not loaded at all with 19% idle and no I/O wait.  I'm even wondering why you'd worry about performance in such a situation.

Comment: I saw `wa`, on the row of `CPU`, but it's related to disk IO? The pictures are just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Then I agree that this question becomes off-topic as unreproduceable and too broad.  `wa` refers to `I/O wait` by the way.